# How to optimize a LINQ with minimum and additional condition

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Asume we have a list of objects (to make it more clear no properties etc.pp are used)

```
public class SomeObject{
    public bool IsValid;
    public int Height;
}

List<SomeObject> objects = new List<SomeObject>();
```

Now I want only the value from a list, which is both valid and has the lowest height.

Classically i would have used sth like:

```
SomeObject temp;
foreach(SomeObject so in objects)
{
    if(so.IsValid)
    {
        if (null == temp) 
            temp = so;
        else if (temp.Height > so.Height)
            temp = so;
    }
}
return temp;
```

I was thinking that it can be done more clearly with LinQ.

The first approach which came to my mind was:

```
List<SomeObject> sos =  objects.Where(obj => obj.IsValid);
if(sos.Count>0)
{
     return sos.OrderBy(obj => obj.Height).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But then i waas thinking: In the foreach approach i am going one time through the list. With Linq i would go one time through the list for filtering, and one time for ordering even i do not need to complete order the list.

Would something like

```
return objects.OrderBy(obj => obj.Height).FirstOrDefault(o => o.IsValid);
```

also go twice throught the list?

Can this be somehow optimized, so that the linw also only needs to run once through the list?

Comment: You can do this rather efficiently in Linq using the .Aggregate() function, but that would not qualify as "being done more clearly". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this with Linq is as follows:

```
var result = objects.Aggregate(
    default(SomeObject),
    (acc, current) =>
        !current.IsValid ? acc :
        acc == null ? current :
        current.Height < acc.Height ? current :
        acc);
```

This will loop over the collection only once.

However, you said "I was thinking that it can be done more clearly with LinQ." Whether this is more clear or not, I leave that up to you to decide.

Comment: May i ask why an aggreagte is needed to find the min value?

Comment: @Offler It's not "needed", as several of the other answers here demonstrate. But it is a way to achieve what you want, and a reasonably efficient one too. `.Min()` can't do the job, because you don't want the minimal height, you want the first object that has the minimal height. Sorting is wasteful, as you have noted yourself. So is grouping. This is an efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
IEnumerable<SomeObject> validHighestHeights = objects
            .Where(o => o.IsValid)
            .GroupBy(o => o.Height)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
            .First();
```

This group contains all valid objects with the highest height.

Comment: Doesn't GroupBy and OrderBy[Descending] each run through the list completely?

Comment: +1 @Tim Yep I see. Smart. It depends a bit in the amount of distinct values for Height.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm afraid that a) where will run through entire colelction with this statement, then b) GroupBy will run through entire colelction and create mostly distinct classes, so it won't shrink the amount to be sorted) and at last c) OrderBy willa lso run again through entire collection.

Comment: @Offler: No, i guess you are not familiar with LINQ's deferred execution. So methods that are implemented that way (like `Where`,`GroupBy` and `OrderBy`) yield only what you want. So they do not need to create all groups until they can return one.  You can understand a `Where` as an `if` clause in a loop not as additional loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter would then IEnumerable<SomeObject> validHighestHeights = objects     .Where(o => o.IsValid)
            .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
            .FirstOrDefault(); not do the same thing without the grouping? Can OrderBy be avoided? (i dind not get Min in the statement)

Comment: @Offler: That returns a single `SomeObject` instance (or null). My query returns all `SomeObject` with the highest height.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yep, i wanted to optimize only to get the one with lowest height. So if i understan you correctly it should be optimized by compiler so that the where will not go for an additional run through complete list.

Comment: @Offler: It's not the compiler that optimizes but the linq methods  that use deferred execution. Have a look at [iterator blocks](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) to understand the technical background (it's not magic but a state machine). However, `OrderBy` needs to order all elements  since you want to find lowest height(use `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByDescending` then).  But you could use [`MinBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) from J.Skeets MoreLinq.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
return (from _Object in Objects Where _Object.isValid OrderBy _Object.Height).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
return _Objects.Where(_Object => _Object.isValid).OrderBy(_Object => _Object.Height).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: My problem is somehow with the OrderBy. If i understand it correctly, the query would first run through the entire colelction with where and then additionally do an OrderBy, whihc is one of the slowest operations.

Answer (score 0):

> Would something like
>
> ```
> return objects.OrderBy(obj => obj.Height).FirstOrDefault(o => o.IsValid);
> ```
>
> also go twice throught the list?

Only in the worst case scenario, where the first valid object is the last in order of obj.Height (or there is none to be found). Iterating the collection using `FirstOrDefault` will stop as soon as a valid element is found.

> Can this be somehow optimized, so that the linw also only needs to run
>   once through the list?

I'm afraid you'd have to make your own extension method. Considering what I've written above though, I'd consider it pretty optimized as it is.

**UPDATE****

Actually, the following would be a bit faster, as we'd avoid sorting invalid items:

```
return object.Where(o => o.IsValid).OrderBy(o => o.Height).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The OrderBy method will have to run through the entire list to do its work. So it will go through the first time to create an ordered list (actually more than once, elements will be hit multiple times to sort), and another time to find the first valid item (which, yes, will stop once a valid item is found).

Comment: It won't go through the whole list to find the first item, except for worst case scenarios.

Comment: I disagree - to perform an order-by, it will go through the entire list. You cannot sort without looking at every item.

Comment: Not sure what you're disagreeing with - yes you need to go through the entire list to sort, but not to select a first element satisfying a condition.

Comment: @decPL I though the OrderBy method is one of the slowest in LinQ, therefore is there a way to avoid sorting of a complete, very long list to get the minimum value.

Comment: Then we need to take a step back and talk about your requirements. If you know a thing or two about algorithms, you'll always end up writing code that will perform faster than LINQ, as that's the cost of LINQ being so generic. In modern day IT though, the computational cost of using LINQ is pretty much negligible and the convenience for the dev is pretty noticeable. If you're writing a game engine, or some drivers, you might want to avoid LINQ altogether.